# Generalization of the Beltrami identity to two functions of two variables

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Let $I$ be the functional defined by
$$I[u]=\int_{a}^b L(x,u(x),u(x)')\,dx$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants and $u'=du/dx$. The [Beltrami identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity) states that  if $\partial L/\partial x=0$, then the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)
$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial u}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial u'}\right)=0$$
can be integrated once, giving rise to
$$
L-u'\frac{\partial L}{\partial u'}=\text{constant}.$$

Now assume that $I$ is a functional of two functions that depends on two variables, that is
$$
I[u,v]=\int_a^b\int_c^d L(x,y,u(x,y),v(x,y),u_{,x}(x,y),u_{,y}(x,y),v_{,x}(x,y),v_{,y}(x,y))\,dxdy,$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are constants and $u_{,x}=\partial u/\partial x$, etc. If $\partial L/\partial x=0$ (or $\partial L/\partial y=0$). Is there any identity analogous to the Beltrami identity for the Euler-Lagrange equation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a Lagrangian density ${\cal L}(x,u(x),\partial u(x))$ in  $n$ variables $\{x^1,\ldots,x^n\}$ with no explicit dependence
$$\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial x^k}~=~0$$
along the $k$'th coordinate, there is a corresponding continuity equation
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{d T^{j}{}_k}{dx^j}~=~0,$$
where the [canonical stress-energy-momentum tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Canonical_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) is
$$  T^{j}{}_{\ell}~:=~\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial u_{,j}} u_{,\ell}-\delta^j_{\ell} {\cal L}. $$
One can in principle create a conserved quantity by integrating $T^{j}{}_k$ over (an appropriate region of) the [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane) $\{x^j={\rm const}\}$, cf. [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). Note that the choice of hyperplane is not unique.

Comment: Actually I mean $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0$ or $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=0$, not  $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=0$. This seems to be not what I am looking for.

Comment: I updated the answer.